# symfony application wont load after composer update

Tags: symfony

Ever since I have ran a composer update none of my pages on my application are able to be accessed, I just keep getting the spinning loading wheel.

I have checked the apache access and error logs but can't see anything. Has anyone experienced this before?

Any help greatly appreciated and if I'm missing a key bit of information to help anyone help me please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your php version is suitable. Use 7 if possible.

Optimize again and Clear cache

```
composer install --optimize-autoloader
bin/console cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer, however restarting the laptop worked. I'm guessing restarting apache might have solved the issue.